# Call all methods of a module

Tags: ruby, methods, module, call

I have this module

```
module Example
  def self.test
    p "test"
  end

  def self.test2
    p "test2"
  end

  def self.test3
    p "test3"
  end
end
```

Now I have a method which just should call all those methods in the module

```
def call_module_methods
  #call all example methods
end
```

So it would call:

```
Example.test
Example.test2
Example.test3
```

and the output would be:

```
"test"
"test2"
"test3"
```

Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [it's possible](http://ideone.com/DG4q1U):

```
def call_module_methods
  Example.methods(false).each do |m|
    Example.send m
  end
end
```

The trick is that you need to call [`methods(false)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-methods) in order to get only the methods defined directly on the module.

Comment: Needless to say, any method throwing an exception would halt the chain. To ensure that all methods are called, remember to handle exceptions within the 'each' block.